# Chromium enable seccomp-BPF sandbox on Debian 7

Tags: chromium

I discovered that my version of Chromium (Version 29.0.1547.57 Debian 7.1 (217859)) does not have all the sandbox features turned on by default. Navigating to `chrome://sandbox/` gives results:

```
Sandbox Status
  SUID Sandbox  Yes
  PID name spaces   Yes
  Network namespaces    Yes
  Seccomp-BPF sandbox   No
You are not adequately sandboxed!
```

Can I turn on the `Seccomp-BPF sandbox`? My OS stats are:

```
$ uname -a
Linux compname 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And since I have uninstalled my desktop manager, I normally start Chromium from the commandline like so:

nohup chromium >> /tmp/chromium.nohupout &

However, I have also tried starting Chromium with the `--enable-seccomp-sandbox` flag, and the sandbox still remains off. When I do this, I get the warning message in stderr:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
```

Solutions which do not involve me recompiling chromium from source are preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox of that type aren't supported on kernel 3.4 or lower; you can use the debian backport to obtain a more recent kernel but keep in mind it'll be less stable.